# Python asynchronous timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to make asynchronous timer using **threading** library

I've an endless function that needs to be stoped after a specific period of time has passed

I also tryed thread._stop, os.getpid and os.kill but nothing really works.

Main func that runs endless record function:

```
def main():
    print("Recording")
    while True:
        record()
```

Record function:

```
command = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', url,'-vcodec', 'copy','-acodec', 'copy', destPath]
returnExitCode = subprocess.call(command)
```

Timer:

```
def timer():   
    i = 0
    print(str(i))
    while i < 100:
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
        print(str(i))
    else:
        print("Stopped recording")

        thread_timer.join()
        thread_main.join()
```

Execution of threads:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread_timer = threading.Thread(target=timer, daemon=True)
    thread_main = threading.Thread(target=main, daemon=True)

    thread_timer.start()
    thread_main.start()
    main()
```

So how can i stop record function when the time runs out?

Should i use asyncio for this sort of task?

Comment: to *stop record function* you need to combine/centralize "timer" and "record" functions handling

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest what is fucntion handling? Im not sure i understand